# How to update state in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created chat application using reactjs, nodejs, mongodb. I am storing the data in mongodb but while mapping over messages array it doesn't show messages in chat app why so ?

I am using `message` state variable to store single message and all these single messages are added inside `messages` array (`state variable`). I set `message: "" and date : ""` but what is happening in my case even before displaying message on screen it is set to empty string. How can I map over messages and display all messages in chat app ?

Code:

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const socket = require('socket.io');
const message = require('./model/message')

const app = express();

const mongoURI = require('./config/keys').mongoURI;

mongoose.connect(mongoURI, {useNewUrlParser: true}, function (err,res) {

    if(err){
      console.log("There is error: " + err);
    }else{
      console.log("Connected to mongo database") 
    }

})

let db = mongoose.connection;

db.once('open', function() {
  console.log("Database is now connected");

  let io =  socket(server);

io.on("connection", function(socket){
  console.log("Socket Connection Established with ID :"+ socket.id)

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('User Disconnected');
  });

  let chat = db.collection('chat');

      socket.on('SEND_MESSAGE', function(data){
        let message = data.message;
        let date = data.date;

        // Check for name and message
        if(message !== '' || date !== ''){
            // Insert message
            chat.insert({message: message, date:date}, function(){
                socket.emit('RECEIVE_MESSAGE', [data]);
            });
        }
    });

    chat.find().sort({_id:1}).toArray(function(err, res){
      if(err){
          throw err;
      }
      // Emit the messages
      socket.emit('RECEIVE_MESSAGE', res);
    });

}) 

});


const port = 5000;

let server = app.listen(5000, function(){
  console.log('server is running on port 5000')
});
```

messages.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const MessageSchema = new Schema({
  message: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Message', MessageSchema);
```

chat.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './chat.css'
import io from "socket.io-client";

export default class Chat extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            message: '',
            date: '',
            messages: []
        };
        this.sendMessage = this.sendMessage.bind(this);
        this.addMessage = this.addMessage.bind(this);

        this.socket = io('localhost:5000');
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.socket.on('RECEIVE_MESSAGE', data => {
          this.addMessage(data);
      });
    }

    sendMessage(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      if(this.state.message !== ''){
        this.socket.emit('SEND_MESSAGE', {
            message: this.state.message,
            date: Date.now()
        });
      }
    };

    addMessage(data) {
      this.setState({
        messages: [...this.state.messages, data],
        message: '', 
        date: ''
      });
      console.log(this.state.messages);
    };

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
                <div id="status"></div>
                <div id="chat">
                    <div className="card">
                        <div id="messages" className="card-block">
                            {this.state.messages.map((message, index) => {
                                    return (
                                        <div key={index} className="msgBox"><p className="msgText">{message.message}</p></div>
                                    )
                            })}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="column">
                            <input id="inputmsg" type="text" placeholder="Enter Message...."
                            value={this.state.message} onChange={ev => this.setState({message: ev.target.value})}/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="column2">
                            <button id="send" className="button" onClick={this.sendMessage}>Send</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Screenshot of `console.log(this.state.messages)` :

[image]

Comment: You are setting the state both in the socket function and in `addMessage`. Is that intentional?

Comment: @tholle This line -> `this.setState({ messages: [...this.state.messages, data] })` adds a new message inside existing message array I am not able to understand which one should I keep and which to exclude.

Comment: @Tholle If I remove `this.setState({ messages: [...this.state.messages, data] })` from componentsDidMount then I get multidimesnsional array see this -> https://imgur.com/a/m8PhEBX

Comment: @Tholle I want only single messages array with all messages and no multidimensional arrays

Comment: It seems like `data` is coming as an array from your socket and not a single message. Can you check that?

Comment: @Tholle But if I refresh the page then in console I can see array and not multidimensional why so ? see this -> https://imgur.com/a/ZGTAtgg

Comment: It is multidimensional, just with one element - an array with 21 elements in it

Comment: @VytautasLozickas I have updated the question please check

Comment: @VytautasLozickas Yes that one element is the latest message which gets inserted in database. but after refresh it again shows array with 22 elements i.e 21+1 see this -> https://imgur.com/a/ZGTAtgg

Comment: Judging from your server side code it looks like you do emit `RECEIVE_MESSAGE` as an array and so doing `[ ...state.messages, data ]` results in multidimensional array being created in react. You can either emit a single message via `RECEIVE_MESSAGE` or change your getMessage to do `[ ...state.messages, ...data ]`

Comment: @VytautasLozickas Can you write an answer ?

Comment: @VytautasLozickas getmessage or addMessage ?

Comment: @VytautasLozickas Wow it is working please add an answer. Why changing `messages: [...this.state.messages, data],` to messages: [...this.state.messages, ...data],` work ? I couldn't get it ? why `...data` worked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your server side code it looks like you do emit `RECEIVE_MESSAGE` as an array and so doing `[ ...state.messages, data ]` results in multidimensional array being created in react. You can either emit a single message via `RECEIVE_MESSAGE` or change your `addMessage` to do `[ ...state.messages, ...data ]`.

To explain this more:
So at first your `messages` state is set to an empty array. Then all your old messages comes from socket as an array (data) and `addMessage` gets called and tries to spread elements of `state.messages` (which is still empty at this point) and then adds a `data` (which is an array) in the end of that new array being set to state. The result is that you get an array with one element: all your previous messages (array in array). When new message comes in `addMessage` does the same spreading and so `state.messages` gets spread into a new array and `data` (which is again - an array) gets added to the end of it. The result is array with two elements: the first array (data) that got added in the beginning and the new one. By doing `...data` in `addMessage` function you're spreading the actual array of data and putting its elements into the state but not the array itself so `[ ...state.messages, ...data ]` acts like a concatenation of elements in two arrays: `state.messages` and `data`.